# Is app data wiped every time debug/deploy? android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was wondering whether user data gets wiped every time I debug my app/run in eclipse in the emulator?

Also, do sharedPrefences get wiped everytime an app is killed?

Thank you

:)

Answer (score 1):

By default, User's data doesn't get wiped. However, in run configuration, under Target tab, there is a checkbox(wipe user data). If it is checked, data gets wiped every time.

Answer (score 1):

unless you do clear data in app manager yourself, no user data get wiped.